# How to create category?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Since few hours I am stuck on a specific excel case ...

To summarize: I have different kind of category:

- Category A: Math and physics
- Category B: Math and Music
- Category C: Physic and Sport
- Category D: Sport and Music

The result on my excel file:

| Title | Math | Physic | Sport | Music | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | X | X |  | X | A, B |
| Kate | X | X |  |  | A |
| Steven |  |  | X | X | D |
| Bart | X | X | X | X | A, B, C, D |

How can I have the the different category on the profile ?
It can have 1 or several categories at the same time.

I created this formula but it match only one category and I would like to have all the possibility...

```
=IF(AND(A1="X",B1="X"),"CategoryA",IF(AND(A1="X",D4="X"),"CategoryC",IF(AND(C1="X",B1="X"),"CategoryC",IF(AND(C1="X",D1="X"),"CategoryD","No Profile"))))
```

Thanks a lot ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Excel 365:

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER({"A","B","C","D"},ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"XX??","X??X","?XX?","??XX"},CONCAT(IF(B2:E2=""," ",B2:E2)))),"No Profile"))
```

---

Or the fancy way using `BYROW()` to spill results:

```
=BYROW(B2:E5,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER({"A","B","C","D"},ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"XX??","X??X","?XX?","??XX"},CONCAT(IF(x=""," ",x)))),"No Profile"))))
```

[image]

Comment: Great ! Working on an excel file but not on google sheet don't know why

Comment: @dole, because Google Sheets and Excel are different application. Though they may look alike, they are completely different.